# If threading shares the same file descriptor table, how does each thread read a different part of the file?

Tags: linux, file, pthreads, file-descriptor, file-management

I understand that threads share almost everything in the PCB (except PC and stack), including the file descriptor table. The file descriptor table entry is a pointer to the system wide open file table, where each entry has a Op.Type, File offset and File Data. If a process is opening a file and creates multiple threads reading from the same file (file descriptor) using system call read, why will each threads read a different part of the file? (Given they access the same file descriptor in the same table, and thus same file and same offset?)

Comment: What do you mean "read a different thing". Please show some code and some examples to make your question clearer. If the threads are using the same file descriptor then if any thread does a read it will move the file offset for all threads. Hence when another thread does a read it will not be the same as what the first thread read but rather continues from where the first thread stopped reading.

Comment: I mean the content of the file. But that answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanker

Comment: Note, each thread can still open the file seperately and read using different file descriptors. In that case the fds are in the same table but since the threads are using different entries in the table they can both read independently.

Comment: If you want multiple threads to use the same descriptor and have their own offsets, use pread/pwrite and keep track of the offsets manually.

Comment: I think I see what you're really asking here: "If two different processes or threads concurrently `read` from FDs referring to the same open file description, is it guaranteed that all of the file's data will be read by one process or the other, with no data either skipped or read by both?" If so, please edit your question to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Kaylum:
If the threads are using the same file descriptor then if any thread does a read it will move the file offset for all threads. Hence when another thread does a read it will not be the same as what the first thread read but rather continues from where the first thread stopped reading.

So they do access the same entry on the system wide file table, but since each thread changes the file offset for all the threads, they do not read the same part of the file.